# How to get _id field from table and put it into ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

I'm beeing bit confused here.

```
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.bugs_list_item, itemCursor, 
            new String[] {db.KEY_ROWID, db.BUGS_DATE, db.BUGS_DESCRIPTION}, 
            new int[] {R.id.bug_id, R.id.bug_date, R.id.bug_description});
```

This basically shows me a ListView with date and description but no id (I just get blank space in place of id). _id field is primary key, it's an integer.

See how it looks on the img

[image]

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="1" 
    >
        <TableRow 
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView             
            android:id="@+id/bug_id" 
            android:layout_width="5dip" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="3dip"                      
            >
            </TextView>
            <TextView            
            android:id="@+id/bug_date" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="3dip"
            android:gravity="right"
            >
            </TextView>
            <TextView            
            android:id="@+id/bug_description" 
            android:layout_width="180dip" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="3dip"
            android:gravity="right"
            >
            </TextView>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
```

create table query:

```
BUGS_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE bugs (_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, date DATE DEFAULT (DATETIME('NOW')) NOT NULL, description TEXT) ";
```

Comment: So you want to Display the Item id with the listview na?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue:

```
    android:layout_width="5dip"             
    android:padding="3dip"
```

Layout width was only 5px, when I padded text by 3px it probably dissapeared below another layout... geez

Answer (score 0):

It's very important that your "id-field" does have the name "_id", else it might not work.

Comment: kinda dunnno why it's important, I was following samples, but yeah, it does have it

Answer (score 0):

whats the XML of your list view rows look like? have you set the ID correctly?

**EDIT:**
Since your XML file seems to be set up correctly, I now believe your problem is something else. It could be that the data for the bug_id field is not being stored or retrieved properly from your database.

This is from android docs:
'Be sure to include an integer column named "_id" (with the constant _ID) for the IDs of the records. You should have this field whether or not you have another field (such as a URL) that is also unique among all records. If you're using the SQLite database, the _ID field should be the following type:

INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT'

Try to change your create table SQL to give your bug_id field an alias like this:

```
bug_id as _id integer primary key autoincrement,
```

as opposed to:

```
bug_id integer primary key autoincrement,
```

Comment: bug_id as _id integer primary key autoincrement +  sqlite doesnt really seems to like it, it says it's caused by "as"

Comment: tried even to create  additional column bug_id, which I made primary key, but it's not beeying listed aswell

Answer (score 0):

Simply get the ID's from this code & paste this code to your Database.java file -

```
String[] return_result()
{

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(tableName, new String[] { "_id", "date", "description"},null, null, null, null, null);
    String[] result = new String[cursor.getCount()];
    int i = 0;
    if(cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        do
        {
            result[i]= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
            i++;
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    if (cursor!=null && !cursor.isClosed()) 
    {
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
    }
    return result;
}
```

In your main java file use like this -

```
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.bugs_list_item, itemCursor, 
        new String[] {db.return_result(), db.BUGS_DATE, db.BUGS_DESCRIPTION}, 
        new int[] {R.id.bug_id, R.id.bug_date, R.id.bug_description});
```